# Does $ z_1 + ... + z_n = 0 $ imply $ \lbrace z_i \rbrace _i = \lambda \mathbb{U}_n $?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let  $ n \ge 2  $  be an integer and  $ (z_i) \in \mathbb{U}^n $ such as  $ z_1 +... + z_n = 0 $ .
I look for an extra condition on these complex numbers that would give $ \lbrace z_i \rbrace_i = \lambda \mathbb{U}_n  $ for one  $ \lambda \in \mathbb{U} $ .
I found that no condition has to be added when  $ 3 \ge n $ ,  but there is a problem when  $ n = 4 $ , and more generally when  $ n  $  is even ( $ 1-1+ ... +1-1 = 0$ ).

Comment: What is $\mathbb{U}_n$?

Comment: The group of the  $ n $-th roots of unity.

Comment: Und what are $\mathbb{U}^n$ and $\mathbb{U}$?

Comment: Respectively the  $ n $ -fold Cartesian product of the unit circle and the unit circle.

Comment: It is a different problem, but you might be interested in the following fact: if you have $\theta_0=0 \le \theta_1 \le \cdot\cdot\cdot \le \theta_n \le 2\pi$ real numbers such that for $k \in [\![1,n]\!]$, $0\le \theta_k - \theta_{k-1} \le \frac{2\pi}{n}$ and $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \exp (i \theta_k) = 0$, then for all $k\in [\![1,n]\!]$, $\theta_k = \frac{2k\pi}{n}$.